# Strange error loading texture from .bmp openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap, ifstream, texture-mapping

My openGL program only renders half of the texture. I used the following code to load a 24Bit .bmp.

```
unsigned char header[54]; // Each BMP file begins by a 54-bytes header
unsigned int dataPos;     // Position in the file where the actual data begins
unsigned int width, height;
unsigned int imageSize;   // = width*height*3
// Actual RGB data
unsigned char * data;

std::ifstream file("fnai.bmp");

if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Could not open file: " << "C:\\Users\\Danne\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\02 - OpenGL\\BTH24.bmp "<< std::endl;
}
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
    file.get(c);
    header[i] = c;
}
if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
    std::cout << "Incorrect or corrupt bmp file" << std::endl;
}
dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);
if (imageSize == 0) {
    imageSize = width*height * 3;
}
if (dataPos == 0) {
    dataPos = 54;
}
data = new unsigned char[imageSize*3];

for (int i = 0; i < imageSize*3; i++) {
    file.get(c);
    data[i] = c;
}
file.close();
```

When loading a texture, the texture loads and openGL receives the texture but fails to render it completely and the result end up like [image]

After trying different images it failed at different parts of the texture.
Does anyone recognize this error?

Comment: I would suggest using an image library instead of re-inventing the wheel. At least then, if it fails you'll know its on the rendering side.

Comment: What do you mean by "openGL resizes the texture"?

Comment: `imageSize` is wrong, for starters. `.bmp` (Device Independent Bitmap) store scanlines on 4-byte boundaries. The actual size of the image is larger than simply `width * height`, you have to account for extra storage at the end of every scanline to satisfy the 4-byte alignment. This isn't a big issue for bitmaps with alpha channels, but it is a huge issue for RGB (24-bit).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be bit depth of your bitmap. You should try using this with a 24 bit (bit depth) bmp file. When saving file in photoshop as bmp you can change the bit depth. I personally don't know why only 24 bit work, but I recommend trying it.